# The "fun" tag and off-topic early questions

Tags: discussion, off-topic, fun

the inevitable Joke and Quote questions are already up... how will they be dealt with?  Some have already pointed out that they are off-topic according to the FAQ... but similar questions helped to build the community on the StackOverflow site in the early days.  Will the community let it pass for now and lock the questions later?

Comment: Related: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27/when-is-off-topic-relevant-enough-to-be-acceptable

Answer (score 1):

I will reiterate my answer from the [Gaming beta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/should-we-allow-poll-questions/21#21) re polls, meta, humor, etc.:

> My theory on this is simple:
>
> On StackOverflow, the early days allowed a certain amount of meta, poll and subjectivity in questions. As a result, in later months, after the system sorted itself out a bit better, newer users would point to those questions and then ask, "why was *mine* closed if programming jokes is still open?"
>
> I would say the smart answer, if you don't want to be cleaning these up long-haul, is to nip them in the bud early, close them down, and get the rules straightened out clearly and succinctly.

We are asking for a world of pain to not shut those down *quickly* while in beta. That pain may not be today, tomorrow, next month or even in autumn, but it *will* come.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to see why quote and joke questions are not valid on photo.stackexchange.com.
If it is off topic according to the FAQ then it is time to change the FAQ.
If you are going to close those then you need to close so many other questions - what is your favorite photographer/blog,...

You should focus on good answers not stupid rules.

Comment: I have voted to close many discussion polls.  "This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!" is a guiding principle for all SE sites, and included in all FAQs.  "[List of X questions] are not really what we want" (from [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason), among many others on this topic).